# SQL statement switching values and not inserting to database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am running this php script from an ajax call:

```
<?php

    require_once('myConnectDB.inc.php');

    //add beer to database code
    $uID = $_GET['uID'];
    $uName = $_GET['uName'];
    $fID = $_GET['fID'];
    $fName = $_GET['fName'];

    //data from ajax call: "uID="+reqID+"&uName="+reqName+"&fName="+frID+"&fID="+frName,

    //add above data to database
    $db = new myConnectDB();
    error_log("Successfully created DB");                       


    error_log("uid" . $uID);    
    error_log("uName" . $uName);    
    error_log("fID" . $fID);    
    error_log("fName" . $fName);    

    $query3 = "INSERT INTO friends (userID,userName, friendID, friendName, friend) VALUES ($uID, '$uName' ,  $fID , '$fName' , 1 )";
    $result = $db->query($query3);

    error_log("Ran query [$query3] and got result: " . print_r($result, true));

    ?>
```

I inserted error_log to try and figure out why my query was not inserting into my database. Here is the output of my log:

```
[10-Sep-2012 20:36:54] Successfully created DB
[10-Sep-2012 20:36:54] uid6
[10-Sep-2012 20:36:54] uNametest
[10-Sep-2012 20:36:54] fIDmike
[10-Sep-2012 20:36:54] fName3
[10-Sep-2012 20:36:54] Ran query [INSERT INTO friends (userID,userName, friendID, friendName, friend) VALUES (6, 'test' ,  mike , '3' , 1 )] and got result:
```

What I find odd here while looking at the error log is it seems some place in my php it switches the values oof fname and fID there values should be swapped.

Is this screwy or am I over looking something obviousness?

Comment: Sorry guys, not at all: It was a simple parameter mixup in the AJAX call. The security problem is isolated from that - this ofcourse doesn't say it's less important.

Comment: I don't see the reason to down vote for an exact duplicate, there was no way I would have found that searching for my problem.

Comment: ..then we can *only hope* this question is closed for being Too Localized or by owner retraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your AJAX call:

```
"uID="+reqID+"&uName="+reqName+"&fName="+frID+"&fID="+frName,
```

this indeed does look as if `fID` would carry `frName`, while `fname` would carry `frID`!

On a side note: You surely appreciate, that a `fName` of something like

```
',1); DROP TABLE friends; --
```

would be quite funny?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I had been looking at it for a really long time,  and it looks like a second set of eyes was all I needed. And yes I will be adding: real_escape_string for some security :-)